# My program doesn't get into my second for loop

Tags: oop, loops, for-loop

While doing some work for my lab in university
I am creating this function where there is a for loop inside another one.

It is not important to know what the method is used for. I just can't figure out why the program doesn't enter the second for loop. This is the code:

```
public void worseFit(int[] array){
  int tempPosition = -1;
  int tempWeight = 101 ;
  for (int x = 0; x < (array.length - 1); x++){
    if (allCrates.getSize() < 1){
      Crate crate = new Crate();
      crate.addWeight(array[0]);
      allCrates.add(crate);
    } else{
      for( int i = 1; i < (allCrates.getSize() - 1); i++ ){
        Crate element = allCrates.getElement(i);
        int weight = element.getTotalWeight();
        if (weight < tempWeight){
          tempWeight = weight;
          tempPosition = i;
          Crate crate = new Crate();    
          if (weight + tempWeight <= 100){ 
            crate.addWeight(weight + tempWeight);
            allCrates.setElement(i, crate);
          } else {
            crate.addWeight(weight);
            allCrates.setElement(allCrates.getSize(), crate);
          } // if
        } // if 
      } // for
    } // if
  } // for
} // worseFit
```

Once the program enters the else part of the code it goes straight 
away back to the beginning of the first for loop.

Would anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Well, if the second for loop is never entered, then clearly the conditional `i < (allCrates.getSize() - 1)` always resolves to FALSE. You did check that values, didn't you?

Comment: put some console output inside your second for loop and see whether it is getting executed or not.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be some discrepancies with the expected values of `allCrates.getSize()`.

If `allCrates.getSize()` returns 2, it will go to the second for loop, but not run it, as `i < allCrates.getSize() - 1` will result in false

You might want to use `<=` instead of `<`

Answer (score 0):

Initialize the variable `i` in your second loop to `0` instead of `1`. Because if your `getSize()` returns 1 the it will not enter the `if` part and after entering the `else` part the `for` loop condition will evaluate to false and hence your `for` loop will not be executed.